# Impossible to update Variable from Variable Group (Library)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to create a build pipeline in Azure Devops that will update a variable in a variable group.

- So I have my variable group :
  [image]
- Then, in my build pipeline, I link the variable group :
  [image]
- In my yaml file I declare the variables :

```
variables:
- group: Validation
- name: BetaVersionClient
  value: '0.0.0.0'
- name: BetaVersionServer
  value: '0.0.0.0'
```

- Later on in the same file I set the variables :

```
- task: VariableSetTask@1
  displayName: 'Set variable'
  inputs:
    VariableName: BetaVersionClient
    Value: '$(AssemblyInfo.AssemblyVersion)'
```

The variable is updated for the job duration but not in the library holding the variable group.

What am I missing here ? How can I update the library variables from my yaml file ?

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer update resolved your question,  If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT Still under test as I will only be able to make another attempt tomorrow. As soon as I have a result I will share it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First part will be assumptions but it looks that Azure DevOps takes snapshot for build execution. This is why you see this for specific run but not in general. This is probably done in that way because groups may be shared accros build definitions and thus one piepline can may a change for another one.

If this is what you want to do you can use REST API or CLI.

For CLI you have this [command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/pipelines/variable-group/variable?view=azure-cli-latest#ext-azure-devops-az-pipelines-variable-group-variable-update)

```bsh
az pipelines variable-group variable update --group-id
                                            --name
                                            [--detect {false, true}]
                                            [--new-name]
                                            [--org]
                                            [--project]
                                            [--prompt-value {false, true}]
                                            [--secret {false, true}]
                                            [--value]
```

I don't recall if there is devops extension already installed on agent, so you may be interested also about [installing it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/?view=azure-devops).

Another option is to use [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/variablegroups/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) and this endpoint:

```
PUT https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/{groupId}?api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

Example how to call REST API from a pipeline you can find here: [How to send post build message in azure DevOps YAML pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61707263/how-to-send-post-build-message-in-azure-devops-yaml-pipeline/61727753?noredirect=1#comment109272679_61727753)

**EDIT**

This is how you can change variable in variable group:

```yaml
variables:
  orgName: 'thecodemanual'
  variableGroupId: 3

steps: 
- pwsh: |

    $url = "https://dev.azure.com/$(orgName)/$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/$(variableGroupId)?api-version=5.1-preview.1"
    $variableGroup = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"}
    Write-Host "Pipeline = $($variableGroup | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"

    $variableGroup.variables.name.value = "fromPipeline"

    $json = $variableGroup | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100

    Invoke-RestMethod -Method PUT -Uri $url -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"} -Body $json
  name: initial
  env:
    SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(system.accesstoken)
```

And if you get this error:

> {"$id":"1","customProperties":{"Descriptor":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.ServiceIdentity;a960b165-7bec-46ad-9fa3-a4a754989d4e:Build:4fa6b279-3db9-4cb0-aab8-e06c2ad550b2","IdentityDisplayName":"DevOps Manual Build Service (thecodemanual)","Token":"3","RequestedPermissions":2,"NamespaceId":"b7e84409-6553-448a-bbb2-af228e07cbeb"},"innerException":null,"message":"You do not have permissions to perform this operation on the variable group. A variable group Administrator should add you to the Administrator role.","typeName":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Security.AccessCheckException, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi","typeKey":"AccessCheckException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}

Please check this [Having no permission for updating Variable Group via Azure DevOps REST API from running Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52986076/having-no-permission-for-updating-variable-group-via-azure-devops-rest-api-from)

Comment: Thanks I will go with the Rest API then. Need to figure out proper syntax but it seems to be working.

Answer (score -1):

The code is not working, and it might lead you to a trap if you are new to Invoke-RestMethod. However, the approach is correct.

Comment: Take a look again at [answer] to see what's expected of a complete answer